# Solve for x and y given $|x-y|, 1-|x-y|, x,y,1-y,1-x \ge m$

Tags: inequality, graphing-functions

Let $m,x,y \in (0,1)$. Suppose $|x-y|, 1-|x-y|, x,y,1-y,1-x \ge m$. Solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $m$.

What I tried:

1. $|x-y| \ge m$ and $1-|x-y| \ge m$ tell me $m \le |X-Y| \le 1-m$
2. $x,y,1-y,1-x \ge m$ tell me $m \le x \le 1-m$ and $m \le y \le 1-m$

After some long computation I got these. Are these correct?

1. $x \in (m,1-2m)$, $y \in (x+m,1-m)$, $m \in (0,\frac13)$
2. $x \in (2m,1-m)$, $y \in (m, x-m)$, $m \in (0,\frac13)$

(Of course you could also write with $y$ as the independent variable, but whatever.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A geometric interpretation helps:

a. $x, 1-x \ge m$ constitutes a vertical stripe: $m < x < 1-m$
b. $y, 1-y \ge m$ constitutes a horizontal stripe: $m < y < 1-m$
c. $|x-y|, 1-|x-y| \ge m$ constitutes two 45 degree rising  diagonal  stripes:
for $y<x$:  $m < x-y < 1-m$   ;    for $y>x$:  $-m > x-y > -(1-m)$.

From a. and b. it is clear that no solutions exist for $m > 0.5$.

Now the intersection of a. and b. constitute a square, and the intersection of this
square with each of  the diagonal stripes may constitute a triangle.
The "may" results from the question whether the intersection of this
square with each of  the diagonal stripes exists at all. This will be the case if
the upper left corner of the square meets the lower bound of the stripe, i.e.
if  the point $m, 1-m$ is on the line $-m = x-y$. We have that for $-m = m - (1-m)$ or $m = 1/3$.

So if $m\le 1/3$, we can again use the  lower bound of the stripe to compute the bounds for $x$: We have that $x$ can grow up to the point where that line meets the upper bound of the square, i.e. $y = 1-m$, and hence $-m = x-y = x - (1-m)$ gives $x = 1 - 2m$.

So we can summarize:

1. For  $m > 1/3$, the inequalities allow no solution.
2. For $1/3 \ge m \ge 0$, the regions allowed by the inequalities are the two triangles (mirrored on the diagonal):
   $m\le x \le 1 - 2m$ ; $ m+x \le y \le 1-m$
   and $m\le y \le 1 - 2m$ ; $ m+y \le x \le 1-m$ .

So yes this is what you have got.

Here is a picture which illustrates that for $m=0.2$:

[image]

Comment: wish you made $x$ the independent variable in the last part, so i wouldn't have had to convert. anyhoo thanks!

Comment: I left a lttle bit to you (-;

Comment: actually i think your conversion to y independent is helpful. i kinda think instead of deriving i would just 'guess' and then prove. LOL thanks